# How to count number of occurence of specific field in a collection in Mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb

I have my collection as shown below:

```
 {
    "_id" : NumberLong(366),
    "file" : "xyz",
    "clist" : {
                    "account" : "BFS",
                    "subAccount":"a"
              },
},
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(366),
    "file" : "xyz",
    "clist" : {
                    "account" : "BFS",
                    "subAccount":"b"
              },
},
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(366),
    "file" : "xyz",
    "clist" : {
                    "account" : "HC",
                    "subAccount":"c"
              },
 }
```

In that I have to group by account and count number of subAccount; for example:

```
{ 
  account : "BFS", 
  subAccount : "b", 
  count : 1, 
  subAccount :"a", 
  count : 1
}
```

If for account BFS, subAccount b exists two times, then I should get output like this:

```
{
  account : "BFS", 
  subAccount : "b", 
  count : 2, 
  subAccount : "a", 
  count : 1
}
```

Comment: is `clist` your mongo Document?

Comment: Hi krishna; I have edited your question to make the expected output a little bit more readable. This isn't a criticism; on this site everybody is encouraged to collaborate, to [edit] the question to improve it further. If you have more information you can add, then please edit the question again to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

May this help you...

```
db.coll.aggregate([ {
    "$group" : {
        "_id" : {
            "account" : "$clist.account",
            "subAccount" : "$clist.subAccount"
        },
        "count" : {
            "$sum" : 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $project : {
        _id : 0,
        "account" : "$_id.account",
        "subAccount" : "$_id.subAccount",
        "count" : "$count"
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : "$account",
        "subaccounts" : {
            "$push" : {
                "subAccount" : "$subAccount",
                "count" : "$count"
            }
        }
    }
} ])
```